# Exporting Google Sheet to PDF

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, export, pdf

I'm trying to export the current active Google Sheet to a PDF. The below nearly does what I want but I would like a few changes.

Changes.

1. Save the PDF in the same folder as the main spreadsheet rather than the root drive folder.
2. Use the currently active sheet rather than a defined sheet.

   ```
   function generatePdf() {    
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var mainSheetName = 'Barney'; //Change 'Main Sheet' to the name of your main sheet
     var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheetName);
     var name = mainSheet.getRange('C2').getValue(); //Gets the pdf name from cell B6
     var sheets = ss.getSheets(); //Pulls all sheets as an array

     for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { //Iterates through all sheets
       if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== mainSheetName) { //Hides all sheets that are not the main one
         sheets[i].hideSheet()
       }
     }

     DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name)); //Exports the main sheet

     for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { //Brings back all sheets that were hidden
       sheets[i].showSheet()
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  const mainSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

...and this:

```
  const pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name));
  const folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  pdfFile.moveTo(folder);
```